# Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, dllimport

I have a winform application which is trying to send some data over a serial port.  In there, I am using a native DLL, but I am getting this error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt in VB.Net

Here's what I am doing:

```
Public Declare Function AddScreen Lib "BX_IV.DLL" _
    ( _
    ByVal nControltype As Integer, _
    ByVal nScreenNo As Integer, _
    ByVal nWidth As Integer, _
    ByVal nHeight As Integer, _
    ByVal nScreenType As Integer, _
    ByVal nPixelMode As Integer, _
    ByVal nDataDA As Integer, _
    ByVal nDataOE As Integer, _
    ByVal nRowOrder As Integer, _
    ByVal nFreqPar As Integer, _
    ByVal pCom As String, _
    ByVal nBaud As Integer, _
    ByVal pScoketIP As String, _
    ByVal nScoketPort As Integer, _
    ByVal pScreenStatusFile As String _
    ) As Integer
```

And I am calling it from the form load event with all of the parameters, like this:

```
AddScreen _
    ( _
    CONTROLLER_TYPE_4T1, _
    SCREEN_NO, _
    SCREEN_WIDTH, _
    SCREEN_HEIGHT, _
    SCREEN_TYPE, _
    1, _
    SCREEN_DATADA, _
    SCREEN_DATAOE, _
    SCREEN_ROWORDER, _
    SCREEN_FREQPAR, _
    SCREEN_COMM, _
    SCREEN_BAUD, _
    SCREEN_SOCKETIP, _
    SCREEN_SOCKETPORT, _
    "C:\\ScreenStatus.ini" _
    )
```

When this function is executing, I am getting that error.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I can't imagine it's causing your problem, but in VB.NET, you shouldn't be putting the double back-slash in the path string.  That's necessary in C# because in C# the backslash is the escaping character.  In VB.NET, there is no escaping character.

Comment: The correlation between odds that unmanaged code crashes and the number of arguments a function takes is exponential.  This beast gives you no odds.  Find the programmer who wrote this and ask him for help debugging this problem.